# Unterschied zwischen -istan, -ei und -ien in Ländernamen

Tags: meaning, suffix

Die Endungen *-istan*, *-ei* und *-ien* sind üblich bei Ländernamen, etwa in *Pakistan* oder *Kurdistan*, *Mongolei* oder *Türkei* und *Serbien* oder *Tschechien*.

Ich weiß, dass gelegentlich auch mehrere Versionen existieren, wie beispielsweise *Tschechei* und *Tschechien* wobei *Tschechei* antiquiert und rechts angehaucht ist.

Aber woher kommen die Endungen und was ist ihr Hintergrund?

Comment: Meinst Du vielleicht *Tschechei* statt *Tschei?* [Dies](http://faql.de/pc.html#tschechei) könnte interessant sein.

Comment: Oh, danke. War wohl schon zu spät für mich...

Comment: Tut mir leid, aber bei dem Artikel wird mir übel.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/-stan) sagt dass die Endung **-stan** aus dem Persischen kommt.

Comment: @MaxRied: Aus reinem Interesse: Warum?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das ist so ein "Man wird ja wohl mal sagen dürfen"-Kryptonaziartikel.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wirkt zumindest auf mich sehr stark so. Schon eine Argumentation wie "Benutzten die Nazis nicht auch den Begriff Frankreich?" ist unfassbar...

Comment: @MaxRied: Naja, das ist schon eine valide Antwort auf eine Reductio ad Hitlerum, welche das zumindest das Argument, das dort wiedergegeben wurde (»Aber die Nazis haben den Begriff *Tschechei* benutzt!«), darstellt – ob es sich hierbei um einen Strohmann handelt, es also eine sinnvollere Variante dieses Arguments gibt, kann ich nicht beurteilen. (Generell ist dem Artikel durchaus anzulasten, dass er die Argumente, auf die er eingeht, und die Ausgangslage nicht ausreichend darlegt, sodass er für mich, der ich noch nie von dieser Problem gehört habe, weitestgehend nicht nachvollziehbar ist.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Es gibt halt Wörter, die durch die NS oder sonst wen belastet sind. Da sind wir uns wohl einig. Aber das betrifft ja nicht automatisch den gesamten Wortschatz dieser Personen. Atmen darf man, obwohl die meisten Nazis das wohl auch getan haben. Hakenkreuze schmieren darf man eher weniger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für `-stan` hat Hulk in seinem Kommentar schon die Antwort gegeben.

`-ei` für Landesnamen leitet sich vermutlich vom „normalen“ `-ei` ab, wie zum Beispiel in [Vogtei](http://dwds.de/?qu=vogtei) oder [Probstei](http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Probst). Es bezeichnet den zugehörigen Bezirk. Die Türkei ist also der Bezirk der Türken.

`-ien` ist vermutlich eine Eindeutschung ähnlicher Suffixe in anderen Sprachen. [Hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologie_der_Begriffe_%E2%80%9ERum%C3%A4nien%E2%80%9C_und_%E2%80%9ERum%C3%A4ne%E2%80%9C) wird das für Rumänien erläutert: *românie* bezeichnet den Stand der Rumänen, also die Rumänenschaft. Syrien könnte vom arabischen *al-suriya* kommen.

Alternativ ist `-ien` einfach eine Entlehnung des französischen [`-ien`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ien), das eine Abstammung oder Zugehörigkeit bezeichnet.