# Herkunft des Ländernamensuffixes »-ei«

Tags: etymology, suffix, place-name

Einige Fragen hier wollen wissen, welches grammatikalische Geschlecht verschiedene Ländernamen haben; dort fällt auf, dass alle Länder und Regionen, die das Suffix *-ei* enthalten,* feminin sind – die Mongolei, die Walachei, die Tschechei, die Lombardei.

In einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/gender-of-country-names-without-articles/10852#comment63903_10852) hat Chieron angemerkt:

> […] Das nicht mehr produktive Landesnamensuffix *-ei* ist feminin […]

Mich interessiert die Etymologie dieses Suffixes. Insbesondere:

- Wann und aus welchen Vorläufern ist es entstanden?

  - Lässt sich daraus gegebenenfalls das Genus ableiten?
- Ist es Zufall, dass fast alle Regionen, die es verwenden, östlich von Deutschland liegen? Warum zum Beispiel nicht (an den Haaren herangezogene Beispiele) die *Galizei* oder die *Burgundei*?
- Sofern die These des Kommentars stimmt, müsste das Suffix in der Vergangenheit deutlich produktiver gewesen sein; lässt sich das belegen/in eine Epoche eingrenzen?

---

*: Nicht alles, was auf *ei* endet, hat auch das Suffix, um das es geht: Die südafrikanischen Regionen *Ciskei* und *Transkei* leiten sich beispielsweise vom Fluss *Kei* ab. Laut Wikipedia ist es aber dennoch *die Ciskei* und *die Transkei.*

Comment: [Diese verwandte Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/12112/15318), die nach den Unterschieden fragt, liefert in meinen Augen keine befriedigende Erklärung.

Comment: Was heißt 'produktiv'?

Comment: @userunknown Dass es für Neuschöpfungen eingesetzt werden kann.

Comment: Und woran sieht man, dass es für Neuschöpfungen nicht eingesetzt werden kann?

Comment: @userunknown Diese Frage bitte Chieron stellen.

Comment: @user unknown: Daran, daß alle _Häh?!_ sagen, wenn du es versuchst.

Comment: @chirlu: So oft werden neue Staaten/Regionen ja heutzutage nicht gebildet. Zwar sind jüngst mehrere Staaten zerfallen, aber Serbien, Kosovo, Ukraine usw. als Begriffe gab es schon vorher. Daher habe ich Deine Häh-Erfahrung auch noch nie gemacht, wa?

Comment: @user unknown: _-nis_ wäre ein Beispiel für ein häufiges, aber kaum noch produktives Suffix; _-ist_ und _-ismus_ Beispiele für häufige und produktive Suffixe.

Comment: @user unknown: Es gewinnen manchmal Regionen an Beachtung, die vorher keine etablierte deutsche Bezeichnung hatten. Trotzdem kam niemand auf die Idee, _Darfurei_ oder _Kundusei_ zu bilden.

Comment: @chirlu: Sieh Dafur und Kundus seit 1800, 1850 belegt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Darfur%2C+Kundus&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDarfur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKundus%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @chirlu "Darfurei" oder "Kundusei" fallen schon darum aus, weil das Suffix "-ei" an eine *Volksbezeichung* angehängt wird und daraus einen Regionsnamen macht. Der jüngste Name auf "-ei" (und auch der geographisch westlichste) dürfte übrigens "Kabylei" sein.

Comment: Keine Zeit für eine gut recherchierte richtige Antwort, aber grundsätzlich gibt es keinen großen Unterschied zwischen dem Ort der Bäcker (Bäckerei) und dem Ort der Mongolen (Mongolei). Das deutsche Suffix *-ei* scheint mir relativ jung zu sein; vermutlich stammt es vom lateinischen *-ia* ab. Bei älteren lateinischen Entlehnungen wurde *-ia* zu *-ien*; bei neueren wurde es dann durch *-ei* übersetzt.

Answer (score 3):

Es sieht aus, dass man vielleicht die Antwort in der altrömischen Geschichte suchen muss?

Nach dem Kapitel "Morphologie und Wortbildung der Ländernamen" in Eichlers *Namenforschung* ([S. 1359](https://books.google.com/books?id=DRVaSFuj2fwC&lpg=PA1359&ots=wGL1LGS8ey&dq=lombardei%20tschechei%20mongolei%20herkunft&pg=PA1359#v=onepage&q=lombardei%20tschechei%20mongolei%20herkunft&f=false)) ist die "-ei" ein romanisches Lehnwort.  Der Autor zitiert Adolf Bach (Heidelberg 1953-4), *Deutsche Ortsnamen*.

"Daneben zeigen spätlat. Ländernamen auf -ia das fremdartige Aussehen von Lombardei, Mongolei, Tartarei, Türkei, Walachei, wozu wieder die Neubildungen Polakei und Wendei." - Friedrich Kluge (1917), [*Deutsche Namenkunde*](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Deutsche_Namenkunde_(Kluge)/E-Book)